# How to get th content of a string inside a request response?

Tags: python, python-requests, openai-api, gpt-3

I was coding a webapp based on GPT-2 but it was not good so I decided to switch to official OpenAI GPT-3.
So I make that request:

```
response = openai.Completion.create(
  engine="davinci",
  prompt="Hello",
  temperature=0.7,
  max_tokens=64,
  top_p=1,
  frequency_penalty=0,
  presence_penalty=0
)
```

And when I print the response I get this:

```
{
  "choices": [
    {
      "finish_reason": "length",
      "index": 0,
      "logprobs": null,
      "text": ", everyone, and welcome to the first installment of the new opening"
    }
  ],
  "created": 1624033807,
  "id": "cmpl-3CBfb8yZAFEUIVXfZO90m77dgd9V4",
  "model": "davinci:2020-05-03",
  "object": "text_completion"
}
```

But I only want to print the text, so how can I do to print the "text" value in the response list.
Thank you in advance and have a good day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the dict indexing by key, and the list indexing by index

```
x = {"choices": [{"finish_reason": "length",
                  "text": ", everyone, and welcome to the first installment of the new opening"}], }

text = x['choices'][0]['text']
print(text)  # , everyone, and welcome to the first installment of the new opening
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try print(response["choices"][0]["text"])

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the same as the previous answer, you're just printing the expression directly instead of saving it first to a variable.

Comment: No, it is not.  I've tested both.  One works and the other doesn't.  Have you tried them out?

This one works too:

print(response.choices[0].text)

Answer (score 0):

I think GPT-3 response structure has been changed, for reference, the response object looks this:

```
const response = await openai.createCompletion({
    model: "text-davinci-002",
    prompt: "Say this is a test",
    temperature: 0,
    max_tokens: 6,
});

// the response looks like the following
{
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  headers: {
  },
  config: {
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
  },
  data: {
    id: 'cmpl-5zzyzqvh4Hmi5yyNL2LMI9ADkLBU0',
    object: 'text_completion',
    created: 1665457953,
    model: 'text-davinci-002',
    choices: [ [Object] ],
    usage: { prompt_tokens: 5, completion_tokens: 6, total_tokens: 11 }
  }
}

// choices can be accessed like this
var { choices } = { ...response.data }
```